# What are some personality traits that don't exist in humans, but may exist with extraterrestrials?

Tags: science-fiction, humans, aliens

For example, humans can be anxious, headstrong, loving, maniacal. These are traits we can empathize and understand as we are also human. But there must be some sort of limit to what these emotions are as we are wired in a specific way.

What are some personality traits that humans don't have that could be seen as 'normal' by another race?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. you are asking for a potentially endless list, with no criteria to pick a best answer. That's not the kind of question we like here. You can find more info in the [help]